# How to set the key repeat rate for an external/Bluetooth keyboard in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

I am using OS X and started using an external Bluetooth keyboard. The main pain area working with the keyboard is the slow repeat rate when a key is pressed. Changing the system preferences only changes the repeat rate of the default built-in keyboard.

How can I change the repeat rate so that it applies to the external keyboard as well?

Answer (score 0):

The slider in System Preferences should normally apply to at least Apple's wireless keyboards.

You could also try using [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en). It also allows setting the key repeat to faster than the maximum shown in System Preferences but slower than `defaults write -g KeyRepeat -int 0`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution Lauri. That worked like a charm.